# Access flashvars in preloader in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, preloader, flashvars

I want to access some flashvars in my preloader to a Flex application. How is this possible?

Regards Adlertz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `loaderInfo.parameters` attribute of the preloader.

Answer (score 1):

From the preloader, you should be able to access the flashvars indirectly through the SystemManager as follows:

```
var systemManager:SystemManager = parent.parent as SystemManager;
var params:Object = LoaderInfo(systemManager.loaderInfo).parameters;
```

Comment: I think the loaderInfo attribute of all sprites in the display tree point to the same LoaderInfo instance, so there is no need to dig up the system manager. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have accessed the flashvars using loaderinfo from the root of my preloader-sprite.

var flashvars:Object = root.loaderInfo.parameters;

The tricky part was to know when the root wasn't null. But I found a blogpost:

http://dndigital.net/blog/2008/08/accessing-flashvars-in-a-custom-flex-preloader/

Comment: root.loaderInfo is the same as loaderInfo, when root is not null, see my comment to Raul's answer.